# How to use automapper in background thread once DI context has been disposed?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, scope, automapper

I have a web API where one of my classes in the service layer injects an instance of automapper via DI.

This service has a method that gets called which begins a task in the background and then immediately returns a result to the caller, while the background task continues to execute. This solution works fine for our use case since all of our dependencies are initialized via DI at the construction of the service, and they are thread-safe too.

There is one exception however - if the background task tries to use the injected automapper instance after the request has returned (and therefore the DI scope has already been disposed) we get an `ObjectDisposedException` because it seems like it is trying to someone access the DI scope, even though automapper is already instantiated so it shouldn't need to.

How can I prevent this behavior? I really don't want or need automapper to access our DI scope at all - once the instance is constructed I just want it to work without needing further access to DI.

Comment: The general rule is to create and manage a scope on a background thread. Services should not be moved from thread to thread (except in the case of asynchronous calls of course). Instead a new parallel running piece of code should get its own scope, and you should resolve services from it. This gives the background thread full control over the scope and its dependencies, without getting any race conditions.

Comment: AM itself is thread safe, you just need to configure it as singleton. `AddAutoMapper` has a parameter that allows you to do that.